# Git- how to checkout a specific version (commit hash) in Teamcity?

Tags: git, teamcity

I have done this for SVN but I can not find any instruction for Git. I want to build from a branch up to a specific commit hash, how to specify the hash in TeamCity? I believe the config should go in to **Branch Specification**.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you do it with SVN?

Comment: Git use the keyword `reset` to change a branch label to point to a specific commit. Maybe you can check for a similar name in Teamcity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If TeamCity knows about this commit (i.e. you can see commit in TeamCity change log), then you can start a build right from this change. There is a small run build icon in change log for each commit. Or you can use custom build and select this change from the list.

If TeamCity doesn't know anything about this commit, then currently there is no way to trigger a build on it, see also http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-5610